# ggpubr error - missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, ggpubr

Here are some simulated data,

```
qwe<-c(1:20)
asd<-c(rep(c("a","b"),10))
ty<-cbind.data.frame(qwe,asd)
```

Now I plot it and I want t-test to compare responses between 2 groups

```
q <- ggboxplot(ty, x = "asd",y="qwe", 
               color = "asd",
               add = "jitter")


my_comparisonsq <- list( c("a, b") )
q1<-q + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisonsq)+ 
  stat_compare_means(label.y = 22, method='t.test')             
q1
```

When I plot it, I get the following error:

```
Caused by error in `if (scales$x$map(comp[1]) == data$group[1] | manual) ...`:
! missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any help is appreciated, lost far too much time on this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mention your comparisons separately in a list and not in one string like this:

```r
library(ggpubr)
q <- ggboxplot(ty, x = "asd",y="qwe", 
               color = "asd",
               add = "jitter")

my_comparisonsq <- list( c("a", "b") )
q1<-q + stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisonsq) +
  stat_compare_means(label.y = 22, method='t.test')             
q1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>